# Visual studio The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and downloaded HTML/Javascript cordova update 6. After successful installation, I've tried to create new project with Cordova template but I got error like below.

"Error while creating sub project 'App'. The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct."

Does anyone got this and solved it ?